# RegEx to exclude a space between country code and phone number itself?

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to create two groups from a full phone number(which is given in a string):

First group: +xyz (any three numbers with a plus sign)

Second group: following 7 or 8 digits

So, my regex is:
((\D?[0-9]{3})(\D?\s?[0-9]{7,8}))

The problem I encountered was that if I have, for example +358 55667788, whitespace after a country code is still included in the second group. Is there any way how to fix this?

String I have looks like this. "+347 56887364  +37256887364
+33359835647"

Comment: what is the info you want to extract from `"+347 56887364 +37256887364 +33359835647"` ?

Comment: +xyz and following 7 or 8 eight numbers, the phone number itself

Comment: I'm sure you are aware, but nevertheless: some country codes can actually be 1-digit, 2-digit (for example Russia +7, India +91 etc.), and even more complicated than that

Comment: Yeah, I know, but currently I have to deal only with those that contain three numbers

Comment: Your assumption of three digits for the country code is false.  As it has been commented, some country codes are 1 and 2 digits, but also 4 digits (for small countries that somehow share prefix with a bigger country)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex pattern:

```regex
\+\d{3}[ ]?\d{7,8}\b
```

Sample script using `re.findall`:

```py
inp = "Here are some nums: +347 56887364 +37256887364 +33359835647"
nums = re.findall(r'\+\d{3}[ ]?\d{7,8}\b', inp)
print(nums)  # ['+347 56887364', '+37256887364', '+33359835647']
```